# How to infinite loop a dataset string

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I am looking for a way to keep on looping a couple of values. I am using a simple ajax load script, which get the value(s)(files) from a dataset from the target element. The re-loading of a file happens every XXXX second, so it will load the file over and over, but if there are more files present it should loop them all, and re-loop it....infinite

The example below is a basic idea how, I split the string and start with the first one, but how can i loop this(the best way), and keep it looping.

***HTML***

```
<div id="target" data-load="file1.php | file2.php | file3.php"></div>
```

***jQuery***

```
var fileTo = $('#target').data('widget-load').split("|");

setInterval(function(){
   $('#target').load(fileTo[0])
},1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a setTimeout("function",delay) to keep calling the same function within itself with a delay for milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

@Diode: in case of infinite loop, shift && push are the better choice. Forgot about them. In that case, I suggest the following:

```
var intervalId = setInterval((function(theArray)
{
    var target = $('#target');
    var current;
    return function ()
    {
        current = theArray.shift();
        target.load(current);
        theArray.push(current);
    };
})($('#target').data('widget-load').split("|")),1000);
```

---

Try this:

```
var intervalId = setInterval((function(theArray)
{
    var target = $('#target');//only search for this once, not on every call
    //to make infinite loop, copy the array
    var resetArr = theArray.slice(0);//use slice, if not a reference is assigned and both arrays will be altered 
    //Name is not required, if you want to use a name, pick a better one, next might be reserved (not sure)
    //best go for nextInterval, chose this one for explanation
    return function next()
    {
        //get first element, theArray is now 1 shorter
        target.load(theArray.splice(0,1)[0]);
        if (theArray.length === 0)
        {//no more files left -> this stops the interval
            //clearInterval(intervalId);
            //intervalId = null;
            //restore the array, the loop starts from file1 again --> infinite loop
            theArray = resetArr.slice(0);//copy the original value
        }
    }
})($('#target').data('widget-load').split("|")),1000);
```

This might be a little dense, but I tried a simple one-line version in chrome console:

```
foo = setInterval((function(arr){ return function(){alert(arr.splice(0,1)[0]); if (arr.length === 0){ clearInterval(foo);}};})([1,2,3]),1000);
```

And it works like a charm. 
How it works:

`intervalId` holds the, erm id of the interval... sort of a reference. As long as that is set, the function will be called every `1000ms`. Instead of passing a simple function as first argument, I created a function, and call it instantly. The argument that I passed to the nameless function (`theArray`) can be accessed by the function called `next`, which is the return value of the anonymous function. It's created inside a function, so it has access to all variables of its *mother* function, even after the *mother* has returned. 
This means that the value of `theArray` is out of scope everywhere else except for the `next` function, which is the actual callback for our interval. Nothing can interfere with the value of `theArray`, nothing can be overwritten by any outside code, making this a vastly safer approach compared to use of globals. 
The same applies to the variable `target`: it was declared and initialized in the anonymous *mother*-function, which is called once and then GC'ed. The variable lives on though, and references a jQuery object. The DOM has only been searched once, for that element, but every new call to the `next` function has access to that object. Do this once and the speed difference is marginal, do this all the time and your scripts *will* be (a lot) more efficient!

So, interval: Every 1000ms, `next` is called. It shifts the first value from the array that was an argument (`theArray`) of its creator (that anonymous function). When that array is empty, the `clearInterval` function is called to stop the lot. All files are loaded, no point in carrying on.
 As soon as this happens, `theArray`, `next`-function, and all other variables (`target`) go out of scope, so no globals, just a nice, clean chunk of memory, which is always a good thing. I'm assuming this code will be triggered as part of an event handler, in which case you can just copy paste this into the handler, and again, no globals will be created.

If this code wíll be part of the global scope, you can easily avoid globals by just wrapping it all up in a self-invoking function:

```
(function()
{
    var intervalId = setInterval((function(theArray)
    {
        //...
    })($('#target').data('widget-load').split("|")),1000);
})();
```

And you're all set. IMHO this is the best, safest and most *JS-minded* approach to this problem. JavaScript is all about functions, the more you *exploit* them, the better the language likes it. In fact, it'll thank you for it by revealing its hidden expressive power.

Even if you decide not to use this answer, read up on stuff like closures and how to get the most out of function scopes. You'll soon catch yourself writing your code a whole new way, promise :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var fileTo = $('#target').data('widget-load').split("|");

setInterval(function(){
   var file = fileTo.shift();   // `shift` gives the file at 0
   $('#target').load(file);     // load it
   fileTo.push(file);           // `push` adds it at the end of the array
},1000);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var $target = $('#target'),
    fileTo = $target.data('widget-load').split("|"),
    i = 0;

setInterval(function(){
   $target.load(fileTo[i]);
   i++;
   if (i === fileTo.length)
      i = 0;
},1000);
```

Comment: Not the best approach, IMHO: 3 global variables, and nothing to stop the interval... this will just keep on loading the same files: file1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3...

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: The question is requesting an "infinite loop". And we don't know if the variables are global. Since this is jQuery, there is a very good chance that the code is in a ready handler.

Comment: Sorry, thought the OP had an issue with that, thanks, I'll adjust my answer to create an infinte loop. Still stand by what I said on the globals, though :-P

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: That's ok :) Yes, the variables should not be made global.